# Silverlight 4 : Uploading file to server

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, file-upload, silverlight-4.0

I need a stable simple file uploader with a progress bar, I have found lots of fancy ones from the search. However, I need the community opinion on which ones to go with?

I have a `FileStream` which I would like to upload to a server, below is a sample server server URL:

```
string uploadUri;
string SavedFileName = "testXRay.jpg"
uploadUri = @"http://localhost/MyApplication/Upload/Images/" + SavedFileName;
```

I am adding a bounty in hope to get a **working** solution which I could use from my SL application. MyApplication is hosted in IIS.